# Disallow timestamps from file on uploaded items

Tags: sftp, timestamp, restricted

I trying to setup my first SFTP server with disallowing timestamp preserve (default option in `WINscp` for example). I always want to take time from the server not from file.

1. First, I make group (`ftpaccess`) and user (user1 and user2 with restrictions).

   a.`sudo adduser user1`
   b.`sudo adduser user2 --ingroup ftpaccess --shell /usr/sbin/nologin
    sudo chown root:root /home/user2
    sudo mkdir /home/user2/ftp
    sudo chown user2:ftpaccess /home/user2/ftp`

Works as expected. User2 gets access only to `ftp` folder.

2. Then I force and ensure that users can't preserve file timestamps during upload. I do that by adding in sshd_config file:

`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P setstat,fsetstat`

That also works but only for user1 without `ftpaccess` group. User2 can preserve timestamp.

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P setstat,fsetstat
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I need Your help and explanation what is the difference between users without any group and those with restricted access. And why `sshd_config` works only for one of them.